# Rails image assets - postpending ")<image.png and breaking image URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, leaflet

I've run into a strange situation with leaflet-rails and its marker-icon.png asset that is bundled with the gem. In my app, I have included my own version of this file in my assets/images folder, which is ahead of the gem's version in Rails.application.config.assets.paths.

When I run this in production, I see the following:

http://beta.pitot.io/flights/2035

As you can hopefully see on the map, the marker appears in HTML as:

http://beta.pitot.io/assets/marker-icon-f8cd76868804022ae9aeb0e99417ccb0ced2db3a9b4e107ec44f4a43ee9a6635.png")marker-icon.png

Including the quote and the paranthese before marker-icon.png.

This doesn't appear in development without asset precompilation, and didn't previously occur before an update to the leaflet gem.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: What does your css look like that produces this line?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to an issue with the rails gem leaflet-rails. Issue here:

https://github.com/axyjo/leaflet-rails/issues/59